# My Controller can't find my (Action)Mailer!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

Greeting all...

I'm trying to figure out a problem that I've never seen and shouldn't be happening by all accounts...

I'm using Rails 3.0.12 with a simple/standard ActionMailer setup:

- I have HelpRequestMailer in app/mailers
- I have HelpRequestsController in app/controllers

First problem... When I call the mailer in my controller...

help_request = HelpRequest.new(params[:help_request])
...
HelpRequestMailer.help_request_email(help_request).deliver

I get the following error: NameError (uninitialized constant HelpRequestsController::HelpRequestMailer)

This in itself is strange.

When I add the following...

require File.expand_path('../../mailers/help_request_mailer', **FILE**)

...To the top of the controller (I would expect the path to be '../mailers/help_request_mailer' but that doesn't work) - which I shouldn't have to do - the controller seems to find the mailer but doesn't seem to recognize what it is/know what to do with it. I get the following error:

NoMethodError (undefined method `help_request_email' for HelpRequestMailer:Class)

Which is technically true... There's no help_request_email class method in HelpRequestMailer... It's an instance method (as specified by the documentation).

My ActionMailer configuration lives in config/application.rb

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: please show your mailer filename and source code.

Comment: class HelpRequestMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "foo@wibble.com"

  def help_request_email(help_request)
    @help_request = help_request

    mail(:to => ['something@something.com', 'me@gmail.com.com'],
         :subject => "[Help request] A help request has been received")
  end
end

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, and it turned out to be a case of a completely unhelpful error message.  In my case it was just a syntax error in some of my code for the action mailer or the associated view.

I think what happened is that when Rails couldn't properly parse the mailer or view code, it just bypassed the files and never instantiated the action mailer object, leading to the error in the controller.

I would have much preferred it if Rails had tripped on the error in the action mailer code itself.